# Regex get value up until a character

Tags: java, regex

An example input would be;

```
$500 has been received from username.
```

So far I have this regex string;

```
$ \\$(\\d+\\.?\\d*) has been received from
```

This should extract the balance (If I am correct?) The issue is, I cannot think of a solution as-to how to get the username. The username string is alpha-numerical so cannot contain fullstops. What would I use to get all characters after the ' ' up until the '.'?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you wanting to capture the value and username only?

Comment: Yes, just the number after the '$' and the username.

Answer (score 1):

According to this site:

http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

This should work:

```
^\$(\d+\.?\d*) has been received from (.*).$
```

Answer (score 0):

`([^.]+)` captures everything until a dot is found.

```
^\$(\d+\.?\d*) has been received from ([^.]+)\.$
```

The reason for the backslashes is that the directly following chars a special chars in the regexp language.

When used in Java it would look like this:

```
"^\\$(\\d+\\.?\\d*) has been received from ([^.]+)\\.$"
```

The extra backslashes here are needed, because in a Java string backslash itself is a special char and has to be escaped.

Comment: Working perfectly, great annotated answer, especially since I am new to java. Thank you very much!

Comment: I hope your application forbid dots in the username ;)