# Java regular expressions / regex

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string:

```
$500 has been received from username [rank].
```

I use the following regex statement to attempt to get the amount paid (500) and the username.

```
"^\\$(\\d+\\.?\\d*) has been received from ([^.]+)\\.$"
```

Unfortunately this is extracting something like this:

```
"username [rank]"
```

I have attempted to modify this so instead of reading until the '.' for the username variable it would read up to the ' ', however the multiple back-slashes seem to be confusing me and I get unexpected results.

What regex 'code' would I need to use to just extract the balance and the username? (the rank is of no use to me).

Many thanks!

Comment: If this is a fixed pattern you don't need regex to do that. `split` on spaces and get the first and one before last parts.

Comment: This is one of many inputs that can be received, if first tests if it fits the pattern so it seemed more logical to just do it all in regex.

Comment: +1 for "_don't need regex_"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this some kind of homework?
The reason I ask is this:

[Regex get value up until a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344296/regex-get-value-up-until-a-character/)

Anyway - according to this site:

http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

This shall work:

```
^\$(\d+\.?\d*) has been received from (.*)\s\[(.*)\].$
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct regex should be:

```
 "^\\$(\\d*\\.?\\d*) has been received from.+\\[(.+?)\\]\\.$"
```

that regex will find whats in the square brackets. To find all the data use:

```
 "^\\$(\\d*\\.?\\d*) has been received from (\\S+) \\[(.+?)\\]\\.$"
```

In that regex, $1 is 500, $2 is username and $3 is rank.

Comment: Doesn't it find rank instead of username?

Comment: I thought that was the point? To find username:

"^\\$(\\d*\\.?\\d*) has been received from (\\S+) [(.+?)\\]\\.$"

Comment: The question states:
"What regex 'code' would I need to use to just extract the balance and the username?" :)